# Laravel new Passport: your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages

Tags: laravel

When trying to this command at cmd: Laravel new Passport

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1

```
- Installation request for symfony/console v3.3.10 -> satisfiable by symfony/console[v3.3.10].
- symfony/console v3.3.10 requires php ^5.5.9|>=7.0.8 -> your PHP version (7.0.4) does not satisfy that requirement.
```

Problem 2

```
- Installation request for symfony/css-selector v3.3.10 -> satisfiable by symfony/css-selector[v3.3.10].
- symfony/css-selector v3.3.10 requires php ^5.5.9|>=7.0.8 -> your PHP version (7.0.4) does not satisfy that requirement.
```

Problem 3

```
- Installation request for symfony/debug v3.3.10 -> satisfiable by symfony/debug[v3.3.10].
- symfony/debug v3.3.10 requires php ^5.5.9|>=7.0.8 -> your PHP version (7.0.4) does not satisfy that requirement.
```

Problem 4

```
- Installation request for symfony/event-dispatcher v3.3.10 -> satisfiable by symfony/event-dispatcher[v3.3.10].
- symfony/event-dispatcher v3.3.10 requires php ^5.5.9|>=7.0.8 -> your PHP version (7.0.4) does not satisfy that requirement.
```

Problem 5

```
- Installation request for symfony/finder v3.3.10 -> satisfiable by symfony/finder[v3.3.10].
- symfony/finder v3.3.10 requires php ^5.5.9|>=7.0.8 -> your PHP version (7.0.4) does not satisfy that requirement.
```

Problem 6

```
- Installation request for symfony/http-foundation v3.3.10 -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[v3.3.10].
- symfony/http-foundation v3.3.10 requires php ^5.5.9|>=7.0.8 -> your PHP version (7.0.4) does not satisfy that requirement.
```

Problem 7

```
- Installation request for symfony/http-kernel v3.3.10 -> satisfiable by symfony/http-kernel[v3.3.10].
- symfony/http-kernel v3.3.10 requires php ^5.5.9|>=7.0.8 -> your PHP version (7.0.4) does not satisfy that requirement.
```

Problem 8

```
- Installation request for symfony/process v3.3.10 -> satisfiable by symfony/process[v3.3.10].
- symfony/process v3.3.10 requires php ^5.5.9|>=7.0.8 -> your PHP version (7.0.4) does not satisfy that requirement.
```

Problem 9

```
- Installation request for symfony/routing v3.3.10 -> satisfiable by symfony/routing[v3.3.10].
- symfony/routing v3.3.10 requires php ^5.5.9|>=7.0.8 -> your PHP version (7.0.4) does not satisfy that requirement.
```

Problem 10

```
- Installation request for symfony/translation v3.3.10 -> satisfiable by symfony/translation[v3.3.10].
- symfony/translation v3.3.10 requires php ^5.5.9|>=7.0.8 -> your PHP version (7.0.4) does not satisfy that requirement.
```

Problem 11

```
- Installation request for symfony/var-dumper v3.3.10 -> satisfiable by symfony/var-dumper[v3.3.10].
- symfony/var-dumper v3.3.10 requires php ^5.5.9|>=7.0.8 -> your PHP version (7.0.4) does not satisfy that requirement.
```

Problem 12

```
- symfony/console v3.3.10 requires php ^5.5.9|>=7.0.8 -> your PHP version (7.0.4) does not satisfy that requirement.
- psy/psysh v0.8.14 requires symfony/console ~2.3.10|^2.4.2|~3.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/console[v3.3.10].
- Installation request for psy/psysh v0.8.14 -> satisfiable by psy/psysh[v0.8.14].
```

Application ready! Build something amazing.

Comment: To solve that issue, first upgrade PHP version. Read error line by line: `requires php ^5.5.9|>=7.0.8 -> your PHP version (7.0.4) does not satisfy that requirement.`

Comment: Please fix the formatting to make it readable.